# Is there a reliable IDE to SATA converter?

Tags: sata, pata

I got a cheap PATA to SATA converter on eBay because my box doesn't have any SATA ports left for the SATA Blu-ray writer I recently purchased.  It only half works, which of course is worse than a clear no.

I can write and read DVDs in a booted system, but I can't boot from it and I haven't managed to write a BD-ROM disc either.

It's as if the hardware instruction set is not complete.

It will also only work on it's own on the PATA channel which doesn't surprise me.

Has anyone had this kind of experience and if so did you manage to rectify it? Is it actually even possible to do this conversion reliably?

I'm also wondering if it's possible to still have a second slave PATA drive but I don't expect so, given that SATA drives are always on their own normally.

Perhaps the drive could be the thing at fault. I've also found that I can't boot from it with a USB SATA converter either, even though I can boot from other CD drives with USB converters. The drive is an LG BH10LS30, perhaps a firmware update could improve things?

Answer (score 3):

I have used this brand in the past with good results, one of the few of this type that actually worked well.

http://www.addonics.com/products/io/ide_sata.asp

Edit, I think I read your question wrong, you have a sata device you wish to connect to an IDE port, this is not a good idea and not sure they make an adapter that does that, I suggest you install a PCI Sata controller card, then connect the BRD to that, or move one of your other sata devices to the card and connect the BRD to the motherboard sata port. Promise brand controller cards is all I have used and have never let me down, they are good quality cards.

http://promise.com/storage/raid_series.aspx?region=en-US&m=572&rsn1=5&rsn3=35

.

Comment: Thanks, have you used with blu ray ? I have the feeling blu ray writiers are more problematic than most other media!

Comment: @barrymac Check my edit above

Comment: Unfortunately the machine is a microATX format and I'm out of pci slots! It does have an e-sata port however, perhaps it's possible to use an external raid box through that, but the esata port does not support port multipliers !

Comment: Me thinks you are trying to do too much with a micro ATX! Sounds like something I would do.

Comment: :-) yes I've even been considering an external pci expansion box, but that would completely be against the point of having a small format